# Location based alarm on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone

I am creating a Windows Phone app and one of the features is triggering off an alarm whenever the user enters the location selected. However, the two background agents available on windows Phone ie Periodic Agent(once every 30 mins) and resource intensive agent(requires phone to plugged in) are not feasible for the function that I want to implement.

Is there no other way than to keep the app open to implement such an alarm?

Comment: Well.. On further investigation, it seems that it is impossible to achieve this function unless the user locks the screen directly from the app page, thereby not pushing the app to the background. I would be happy if someone proves me wrong though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the app as a location tracking app. In that scenario WP lets your app run in background. But be careful this will drain the battery.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691(v=vs.105).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj247548(v=vs.105).aspx

Here are the best practices

However, it could be possible to get the location callback every 15 minutes or so and not drain as much battery.

Comment: I totally forgot to mention that I was using a WP7. But as I have since migrated to a WP8 device, this answer helps me a lot.
Thank you. :)